# LINQ GroupBy result of previous GroupBy

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have a table with data like

```
Year Month Date Sum1 
2019   01   01   11  
2019   02   03   12
2019   02   03   13  
2019   02   04   13  
2019   03   05   14  
2019   03   10   15
```

How I can group that to get a result like

```
2019 +
     01 +
          01  11 
     02 + 
          03  25
          04  12
     03 +
          10  15
      04  13
```

I've tried something like

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, myList>> result= myList.GroupBy(x=>x.Year);
```

but I can't understand how I have to `GroupBy` that result.
I want to group by year, then a month, then date and get total of Sum1 on date level
How I can do that just with LINQ? 
I understand how I can do that within a lot of foreach, but maybe an elegant solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

I created a test object called `myObject`. I assume this is how you're storing your data from the table. If not, please provide your alternative and I will try to adjust.

Your LINQ could look like this: First it groups by all three properties (Year, Month, Date) all at once, then `Select` the Sum of each group.

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(o => new { o.Year, o.Month, o.Date })
                .Select(o => new myObject() {
                    Year = o.Key.Year,
                    Month = o.Key.Month,
                    Date = o.Key.Date,
                    Sum1 = o.Sum(x => x.Sum1)
                });
```